# How to select rows without N/A value in Excel using formula

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet that's pulling data from two outside excel sheets and putting them into a table. Right now, I am using a filter to view the table rows that do not have an N/A value in them.

How can I output the table in a different sheet while selecting only rows without an N/A value in them?

For example...

ORIGINAL DATA:

| NAME | TITLE | ID NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN DOE | MANAGER | #N/A |
| GROVER CLEVELAND | LABORER | 3948 |
| JIM DAVIS | LABORER | 9876 |
| JANE DOBSON | MANAGER | #N/A |
| EMILY BRAY | LABORER | #N/A |
| ALICIA EMERSON | REGIONAL MANAGER | 3322 |

RESULT:

| NAME | TITLE | ID NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GROVER CLEVELAND | LABORER | 3948 |
| JIM DAVIS | LABORER | 9876 |
| ALICIA EMERSON | REGIONAL MANAGER | 3322 |

Thank you for your help.

I thought about using VSTACK and LAMBDA.

Comment: `FILTER` seems easier?

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about programming in Excel. I was hoping for some guidance.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the range `A1:C6`, then:

```
=FILTER(A1:C6, ISNUMBER(C1:C6))
```

for selecting just numeric values. If you want explicitly to exclude `#N/A`, then you can use:

```
=FILTER(A1:C6, NOT(ISNA(C1:C6)))
```